# If gcd (a,b)=1 and gcd (c,d)=1 and a/b=c/d, prove a=c and b=d

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I proceeded this way:

gcd(a,b) = 1 leads to ax + by = 1

gcd(b,c) = 1 leads to cl + dm = 1

**a/b = c/d = k and ax+by = cl+dm**

Then I trying to operate the equation so that I end up finding **k=1** but Im stuck at:

**lets a = ck and b = dk**

**ckx + dky = cl + dm**

**k(cx+dy) = cl + dm**

**k = 1/(cx+dy)**

and nothing tells me that **cx+dy=1** since we have to prove that a=c and b=d

Help please?

Comment: You are probably overthinking.  First I think $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers (otherwise the claim is false).  Just write $ad=bc$.  Use the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to show that $a\mid c$.  Use the fact that $\gcd(c,d)=1$ to show that $c\mid a$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$ad=bc\implies {a|c\to c=ak_1\\ d|b\to b=dk_2}$$Now, since $ad=bc$, what do we conclude?